# Stack Overflow in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have this register that registers all the objects I need:

```
public static class ObjectRegister
{
    public static List<IObject> RegisteredObjects = new List<IObject>();
    static ObjectRegister()
    {
        RegisteredObjects.Add(new Object1());
        RegisteredObjects.Add(new Object2());
        RegisteredObjects.Add(new Object3());
    }
}
```

Next I have this function that checks a list and if the items in the list pass the test, it creates an object instance and adds it to the list:

```
public static List<IObject> Scan(List<parametar> list)
    {
        List<IObject> neededObjects = new List<IObject>();
        foreach (IObject registeredObject in ObjectRegister.RegisteredObjects)
        {
            foreach (parametar param in list)
            {
                if (registeredObject.Test(param)) //returns true or false 
                {
                    neededObjects.Add(registeredObject.CreateInstance(param));
                }
            }
        }
        return connectedObjects;
    }
```

Here is the CreateInstace method for Object1:

```
public IObject CreateInstance(parametar param)
    {
        return new Object1(param);
    }
```

And here is the constructor:

```
public Object1(parametar newParam)
    {
        this.param = newParam;
    }
```

It keeps trowing StackOverflow exception on this line:

```
this.param = newParam;
```

Tried all the possibilities for creating an instance, default constructor, empty object etc etc, but nothing worked... any ideas?

Thanx

EDIT:
Code to the Object1 class:

```
public class Object1: IObject
{
    public parametar param
    {
        get { return this.param; }
        set { this.param = value; }
    }

    internal Object1() { }

    public Object1(parametar newParam)
    {
        this.param = newParam;
    }        


    public bool test(parametar param)
    {
        // I do the propper checking of the param here, and return the result
    }


    public IObject CreateInstance(parametar param)
    {
        return new Object1(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code for your Object1 class.

Comment: Do you really have a class called `parametar`?

Comment: `code` public class Object1: IObject
    {
        public parametar param
        {
            get { return this.param; }
            set { this.param = value; }
        }

        internal Object1() { }

        public Object1(parametar newParam)
        {
            this.param = newParam;
        }        


        public bool test(parametar param)
        {
            // I do the propper checking of the param here, and return the result
        }


        public IObject CreateInstance(parametar param)
        {
            return new Object1(param);
        }
    } `code`

Comment: @user1064633: Don't include the code in comments - put it in the question. Ideally, post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is your problem, in Object1:

```
public parametar param { get { return this.param; } set { this.param = value; }
```

That property calls itself recursively - which is exactly why you're getting a stack overflow. Don't do that. Instead, you probably *either* want an automatically-implemented property:

```
public parameter param { get; set; }
```

or use a private backing field:

```
private parametar param;
public parametar Param { get { return param; } set { param = value; }
```

Additionally, I'd strongly recommend that you start following [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx), and pay attention to spelling in type and member names.

So you probably want your class to be called `Parameter` - although personally I'd at least *try* to make it a little bit more descriptive, e.g. `QueryParameter` or something similar. Likewise `Object1` isn't exactly a semantically-meaningful name - I hope it's not the name in your *real* code.

Comment: Thanx :) that was the problem